# In TypeScript conditional types, how can I test for the presence of a function/generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

I am trying to write a simple function in TypeScript akin to the following JavaScript example (my actual use-case is complex so I've reduced the problem to a simpler use-case):

```
function resolve(value, defaultValue=null) {
  if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
    return value;
  } else {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```

I have a function for resolving nullable variables to their real values. If the parameter is null or undefined, a default value is returned. The default for the default value is null. The motivations for such a function are debatable so we'll assume this function helps enforce a coding standard or something.

Let's observe the semantics:

```
function resolve(value, defaultValue=null) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

let a = resolve(undefined); // null
let b = resolve(2); // 2
let c = resolve(13, 0); // 13
let d = resolve(null, ''); // ''

let myVar = 'some-value'; // get value from somewhere, could be anything (not just a hard-coded string)

let e = resolve(myVar); // Could be typeof myVar or null
let f = resolve(myVar, 0); // Could be typeof myVar or number (cannot be null)
let g = resolve(myVar, ''); // Could be typeof myVar or string (cannot be null)
```

If you pass in a nullish value, you get the default value. If you don't specify the default value, the default default is null. If you pass in a default value that is not null, there is NO WAY to get null. The only way to get null is to pass it in explicitly or omit the `defaultValue` parameter entirely. 
This seems like a good candidate for conditional types. However, I can't seem to wrangle it. This is possibly because this is not possible, based on some of the semantics of TypeScript.

Let me show you what I am trying to achieve. The following does NOT compile:

```
function resolve<T, TDefault extends T>(value: T | undefined | null, defaultValue?: TDefault): T | (typeof defaultValue extends undefined ? null : TDefault) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      return value;
    } else {
      if (defaultValue !== undefined) {
        return defaultValue;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

  let myVar: string | undefined = 'some-value'; // get value from somewhere, could be anything (not just a hard-coded string)

  let e = resolve(myVar); // Should return string | null
  let f = resolve(myVar, 0); // Should not compile. Number is not assignable to string
  let g = resolve(myVar, ''); // Should return string, always.
```

Specifically take a look at the return type:

```
T | (typeof defaultValue extends undefined ? null : TDefault)
```

I hope you can see what I'm going for here. If the parameter `defaultValue` is undefined (omitted) then the return type is `T | null`, otherwise the return type is `T | TDefault` (however, `TDefault` extends `T`, so the ACTUAL return type is just `T`). I know that what I have does not work, or even really make sense. I have written it for demonstrative purposes only. `typeof defaultValue` is equivalent to writing `TDefault | undefined`, so the conditional type I have written is distributive, etc. 
I've tried a variety of different things but I can't seem to get it. I am wondering if the semantics of this function are even possible to be captured by TypeScript.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you use case would be better served by overloads.

```
function resolve(value: undefined| null) : null
function resolve<TDefault>(value: undefined| null, defaultValue: TDefault) : TDefault
function resolve<T, TDefault extends T>(value: T, defaultValue: TDefault) : T | TDefault
function resolve<T>(value: T) : T | null
function resolve(value, defaultValue=null) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

let a = resolve(undefined); // null
let b = resolve(2); // number
let c = resolve(13, 0); // This one is an error since 0 does not extends 13, but maybe this should be the behaviour ? 
let d = resolve(null, ''); // ''

let myVar = 'some-value'; // get value from somewhere, could be anything (not just a hard-coded string)

let e = resolve(myVar); // string | nul
let f = resolve(myVar, 0); // err
g = resolve(myVar, ''); //string
```

Comment: Hi there, apologies for this huge delay. I intentionally tabled this project because I was too close to it. This seems to do the trick. I have refactored my method (which is slightly different to the simplified example above) and it seems to work and make sense now. This answer + taking a break from the project has really helped, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to hard. You type definitions shouldn't have a conditional parameter, instead specify all options. Why? Code defines the logic, the type definitions only define possible inputs and outputs.

```
 (typeof defaultValue extends undefined ? null : TDefault)
```

seems to compile in the playground, but really all the output you need is:

```
function resolve<T>(value: T | undefined | null, defaultValue: T | null = null): T | null {
    return value || defaultValue; //for demo purposes
}
```

Since T already defines input of Subclass of T is allowed, you don't need to specify TDefault. Since after executing this function you wont know of result is T or a subclass of T. the only thing you can really do is type check:

```
if(output instanceof SubClassOfT){
    (output as SubClassOfT).SomeSpecificStuf
}
```